# Unite windows to show them by Alt-Tab

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, workspace

I use several related windows for work, tilted at foreground as an entire complex workspace.
Then I press Alt-Tab to switch to the browser, my workspace windows got lost: one appears while others are in background.

Is there any way to unite some windows as one, so then pressing Alt-Tab they appears all, keeping their look and relative location? Or maybe press another hotkey to see all my workspace windows.

Usually there are 4 such windows, sharing the screen as at Windows logo. 
And browser and some other apps like e-mail in background, but I wake them up on full screen sometimes.

Comment: Would [virtual desktops](http://www.howtogeek.com/195962/unlock-virtual-desktops-on-windows-7-or-8-with-this-microsoft-tool/) help?

Comment: Yes indeed. Never thinked about virtual desktop on windows. What kind you can advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Desktops v2.0

> Download [Desktops v2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) from MIcrosoft’s Windows Sysinternals
>   site. Sysinternals was once a third-party collection of tools, but the
>   Sysinternals tools are so useful and powerful that Microsoft bought
>   them all a few years ago.
>
> ...
>
> The first time you switch to a virtual desktop, Windows will “create”
>   it — it’s loading a new copy of Explorer.exe for that desktop. Windows
>   you open on other desktops won’t appear to be open on your other
>   desktops, so you can’t switch to them with the taskbar or Alt+Tab.
>   You’ll have to switch back to their associated desktop first.
>
> Each desktop also has its own separate system tray — so system tray
>   icons from your first desktop won’t appear on your other desktops. If
>   you open an application on your second desktop and it loads a system
>   tray icon, that system tray icon will only appear in the system tray
>   on your second desktop, and not your first, third, or fourth desktops.

Source [Unlock Virtual Desktops on Windows 7 or 8 With This Microsoft Tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/195962/unlock-virtual-desktops-on-windows-7-or-8-with-this-microsoft-tool/)

Screenshots and more information at the reference link above.

---

#### Alternative solutions

For other options see [Top 3 free Virtual Desktop Managers for Windows 8 / 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/free-virtual-desktop-managers-windows)

Comment: Thank you! Desktops is a little flawed couze it unable to move apps  to another vdesk and some apps starts only on main vdesk, but it still very usefull for terminals